# Calculate the difference between two dates as years-and-days but without months?

Tags: date, perl

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two dates (the early date is June 11th, 1847) as a the number of years plus the number of days. If the second date were June 9th of 2021, I'd like to get back 173 years and 363 days.

I've been using this, though it's not quite what I want.

```
my $firstdate = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%Y%m%d')->parse_datetime($papers{$paper}->{'firstday'});
my $today = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%Y%m%d')->parse_datetime($date);
my $diff = $today - $firstdate;
printf("%d years and %d days\n", $diff->in_units(qw( years days )));
```

The output looks something like this:

```
173 years and 29 days
```

Of course, it's obvious why this is the case if I put `months` back into the in_units() method... it's because it's calculating those separately, and with the months included it'd give output of 11 months. Plus 29 days, and that's the 363 I want.

Given the regrettable fact of the occasional leap year, this isn't so simple as using the modulus operator.

Is there an elegant way to do this, or barring that, is there a practical way to do this?

Comment: @jhnc For dates following Feb 29th in the same year, I would expect that June 10th should give give 365 days. In any other scenario, June 10th should be 364 days. I'm assuming that in_units() gives approximately the same thing, it just calculates that in months... I didn't bother testing that though.

Comment: oh, wait, are you saying you don't need arbitrary start date? it is always 1847-06-11 and second date is always more recent?

Comment: @jhnc 2020-02-29 should be 263 days, the following day 264 days. 2019-02-28 should be 262 and 263 for 2019-03-01.

Comment: @jhnc Yeh, it will always be that start date, but the end date might be anything. The example code at least gives me the correct number of years, always rolling over to the correct year difference on some June 11th or another, but for non-June-11ths, I want the remainder calculated as days rather than months+days.

Comment: Instead of a bunch of ->delta functions, DT should have one where you specify the units!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using [`DateTime::Format::Duration`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Duration) to compute how many days are between two dates:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use DateTime::Format::Duration;

# Given a DateTime, return one for the start of its year
sub first_day_of_year {
    my $dt = shift;
    return DateTime->new(year => $dt->year, month => 1, day => 1);
}

# Given a DateTime, return one for the end of its year
sub last_day_of_year {
    my $dt = shift;
    return DateTime->new(year => $dt->year, month => 12, day => 31);
}

sub years_and_days {
    my ($from, $to) = @_;

    my $formatter = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(normalize => 1, pattern => '%j');

    # Compute the years between two dates
    my $diff = $to - $from;
    my $years = $diff->in_units('years');

    # Simple case: dates less than a year apart
    if ($years == 0) {
        return (0, $formatter->set_base($from)->format_duration($diff));
    }

    # Calculate the days by working out the days from the $from date to
    # the end of its year and the days from the beginning of the $to
    # date's year to it.
    my $from_eoy = last_day_of_year $from;
    my $to_soy = first_day_of_year $to;
    my $first_days = $formatter->set_base($from_eoy)->format_duration($from_eoy - $from);
    my $last_days = $formatter->set_base($to_soy)->format_duration($to - $to_soy);
    my $days = $first_days + $last_days;

    return ($years, $days);
}


my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%Y%m%d');
my $firstdate = $parser->parse_datetime('18470611');
my $today = $parser->parse_datetime('20210609');

my ($years, $days) = years_and_days $firstdate, $today;
# 173 years and 363 days.
printf "%d years and %d days.\n", $years, $days;
```

Comment: I suspect there's edge cases this will fail on. Doing more testing...

Comment: Re "*I suspect there's edge cases this will fail on*", Well, there's one place that skipped a day. This was recent (2009). I'm sure there's a lot of oddities like that if you go back to 1847. ...Like the Russians losing 13 days in 1918.